# How to open second spyder console when running it as admin?

Tags: python, console, ipython, spyder, development-environment

**Background:** My Account doesn't have admnin rights, so i always start spyder via anaconda prompt as an admin to have access to my admin created env. Using '-- new-instance' isnt possible after I've started spyder as the command prompt blocks new input.

**Goal:** add a second console to spyder like a second kernel in the first picture, settings are enabled. Is there a way to do this in Spyder directly?

[image]

**Issue:** Once started, I can't start spyder again via command line as the input is blocked as long as spyder is running. obviously calling spyder two times in one command doesn't work. I also can't run spyder.exe as it would only start my local version where I don't have access to my env

[image]

Comment: did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250998/how-do-i-run-two-separate-instances-of-spyder ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run two separate instances of Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250998/how-do-i-run-two-separate-instances-of-spyder)

Comment: That's where i come from, I added some more context pointing out that this approach doesn't work as the terminal is blocking new input as long as the first instance of spyder is running. Closing the terminal also closes spyder

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) If you want to open more IPython consoles, you need to go to the `Consoles` menu and select the entry called `New console`.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba thats exactly what i was looking for thank you. No idea how i cold have missed this option..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carlos Cordobas Answer was the easiest way to do this within Spyder:

If you want to open more IPython consoles, you need to go to the Consoles `menu` and select the entry called `New console`

Comment: But is it possible to open a new console running in a different environment?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this? [Start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window.)

```
start spyder --new-instance
```

Comment: I added some context, pointing out that i can't use any new commands after starting the first instance of spyder