# Run multiple instances in spyder: option to deselect "use a single instance" is greyed out?

Tags: python, ide, spyder

How can I run multiple instances in Spyder 5.1.1?

The prevailing answer online is to deselect the Preferences > Application > Advanced Settings > Use a single instance option, but this is greyed out for me and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Similar question here, but doesn't have the answer I am looking for: [How do I run two separate instances of Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250998/how-do-i-run-two-separate-instances-of-spyder)

[Photo showing greyed out option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R215G.png)

Comment: Have you tried to do a preferences reset to see if the greyed out option becomes available? Also, you can check the `spyder.ini` file (located in your home/user directory inside `/spyder-py3/config`). There the preferences get persisted so you can check for the entry `single_instance` and change the value to `False`

Comment: Good ideas, but neither of these worked. When I change it to false in all 3 .ini files (the standard, the backup, and the default), the option is still checked and greyed out.

Comment: But did you check if you were able to run multiple instances after manually changing the preferences in the `.ini` files ? (the checkbox could be still greyed out but now should be unchecked)

Comment: sorry should have clarified, the box was always greyed out and checked. I think this might be something that needs to get updated w/ Spyder 5?

Comment: I don't think so. Did you restart Spyder after changing the `.ini` files?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.